# What is the meaning of row = line.rstrip("\n").split(",")

Tags: python, python-3.x, char, cs50

I'm working on cs50/pset6/DNA and I want to achieve this: `# Strip \n from each line and convert comma separated elements into list` And I want to understand the meaning of this line:

```
row = line.rstrip("\n").split(",")
```

Can you please explain me what the syntax means and what each part does? Thank you!

Comment: Have looked at the documentation of both methods ? https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: I understand rstrip...

Comment: It's because I'm still new to python, and I didn't know you could just combine two methods like that

Comment: A method like `rstrip` return the string without the trailing space/newline char, so you store it in a variable, or reuse it diretly and call split() onto it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) `rstrip`:

> Return a copy of the string with trailing characters removed.

So, in this case, it will return the `"\n"` at the end of the string.

Also from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), `split`:

> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string.

Therefore, once you have removed `"\n"`, it will return the list of string which are separated by `","`.

### Example

```py
>>> s = "a,b,c,d\n"
>>> s.rstrip("\n").split(",")
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

The way `row = line.rstrip("\n").split(",")`

If the same as following, you can reuse directly the `string` returned by `rstrip`

```
row = line.rstrip("\n") # remove newline char at the end
row = row.split(",")    # separate one string into a list of multiple ones, based on the comma
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the documentation said:

```
 |  rstrip(self, chars=None, /)
 |      Return a copy of the string with trailing whitespace removed.
 |      
 |      If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
```

And:

```
 |  split(self, /, sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
 |      Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string.
 |      
 |      sep
 |        The delimiter according which to split the string.
 |        None (the default value) means split according to any whitespace,
 |        and discard empty strings from the result.
 |      maxsplit
 |        Maximum number of splits to do.
 |        -1 (the default value) means no limit.
```

To sum up, the instruction first remove each `\n` (it is a *new line*). That give one long line. 
 Then cut the line at each `,`. That give a list, each item being a part of the initial long line.

Answer (score 0):

## Example of str.rstrip([chars]):

```
line = "line\n\n"
line.rstrip('\n')
# line is now "line"

line = "li\nne\n\n"
line.rstrip('\n')
# line is now: "line\nne"
```

So it basically removes chars given as an argument from right of the string to the last occurence.

## Example of str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1):

```
line = "1,2,3"
array = line.split(',')
# array is now: [1,2,3]

line = "aebec"
array = line.split('e')
# array is now: [a,b,c]
```

**Your example:**

```
line = "this,is,a,line\n"
array = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
# array is now: [this,is,a,line]
```

So at first it removes newline char from the right of string to the last sequential occurence of newline char and then it separates string into parts by ',' and stuck these parts to array.

## Advice for your problem

Your code will work if line is truly one line.
If its like

```
line = "a,x\nb,z,v\nc,n,j\ndy,j,k\n"
```

then to remove newlines use:
`line.replace('\n')`

## General advice

Your problem wasn't so hard. Have you read the docs or tried to execute
given line in python interpreter? If not please do so next time, the docs would give you the answer in less time than me :)